# Each element in my array gets overwritten by last element push in

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/998woow6/

It is a basic version of a part in my project. Basically, as the question says, when I push an element into my array, every other element already in the array gets overwritten by the last element pushed in.

To rein act the problem :

- Press the `AddToArray` button, this pushes the `nodes` and `edges` in to an object and then pushes this object in to the `thisArray` array.
- Then click either `DeleteNodes` or `DeleteEdges` which pop the last element from either the `nodes` or `edges` arrays.
- Then press `AddToArray` again to push the updated `nodes` and `edges` into an object, then into the `thisArray` array and you'll notice that the original object, the object at index 0, is overwritten by the object just pushed in.

I've tried looking online, it must have something to do with closures, but I'm not having any luck figuring this one out.

Here is the code if it's easier to view here :

```js
var thisArray = [];

var nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var edges = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function addToArray() {
  var thisData = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  }
  thisArray.push(thisData)
  console.log('thisArray')
  console.log(thisArray)
}

function deleteNodes() {

  nodes.pop();
  console.log(nodes)
}

function deleteEdges() {

  edges.pop();
  console.log(edges)
}
```

```html
<button onclick='addToArray()'>
  AddToArray
</button>

<button onclick='deleteNodes()'>
  Delete Nodes
</button>

<button onclick='deleteEdges()'>
  Delete Edges
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're adding reference to an array so each object have the reference to the same array, try to clone the array using slice:

```
function addToArray() {
  var thisData = {
    nodes: nodes.slice(),
    edges: edges.slice()
  }
  thisArray.push(thisData)
  console.log('thisArray')
  console.log(thisArray)
}
```

Comment: Great stuff. I didn't realise I was only referencing, which caused the problem of updating all the elements in the array. Thanks for the help :)